# Remote Desktop Assistance setup

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

How do I setup Remote Desktop Assistance in a LAN environment so me as the admin can:

1. Initiate the connection
2. The user does not have to confirm me access to his/her system

Comment: Both of these are handled by a group policy.

Comment: What about using Remote Desktop Connection since you are the admin?  Then all you have to do is open port 3389 on your firewall for the network you want to connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to be part of either Remote Desktop group or local admin group to initiate the connection.

You will be able to remote onto a machine without any user's confirmation (Since it's Windows 7 and not a Server OS) if there is no users logged on. If a user is logged in, he/she will be prompted that you need to connect and can allow/deny it depending the rights of that user.

Please read this as it's useful and propose you thrid party apps.

[Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/help-with-remote-desktop-how-to-log-in-with/405488d1-7c06-4bfd-ace9-5115284d4ee8)

> *You cannot. Desktop versions of Windows only allow one user at a time, whether local or remote. You would need to run a server version
>   of Windows (Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008) in order for
>   more than one person to log on. The server OSes allow up to three
>   simultaneous logins, local and remote combined.*